# Почему при отправке post запроса возникает ошибка: 405 (Method Not Allowed)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Я получаю следующую ошибку всякий раз, когда пытаюсь отправить данные в форму Flask:

```
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

Код:
app.py

```
@app.route('/create-article', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def createaritcle():
     
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.form['title']
        intro = request.form['intro']
        text = request.form['text']

        article = Article(title=title, intro=intro, text=text)

        try:
            db.session.add(article)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect("/")
        except:
            return "Ошибка"
    else:
        return render_template("create-article.html")
```

create-article:

```
{% block title %}
    1
{% endblock %}

{% block body%}
<div class="container mt-5">
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control"><br>
        <textarea name="intro" class="form-control"></textarea><br>
        <textarea name="text" class="form-control"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Отправить">

    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Может быть Вам поможет это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689364/method-not-allowed-flask-error-405

Comment: Нет, я указал два метода

Comment: https://www.rupython.com/flask-post-405-9791.html

Comment: покажите запросы которые браузер выполняет при отправке формы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я добавил в форму `action=""`
И это заработало.